# Java Streams for Stored Procedures

Tags: java, neo4j, stream, java-stream, java-stored-procedures

I would like to create a stream of certain values and map them to an internal class. My current code is as follows:

```
return Stream.of((int)levenshteinScore, reverseComparison, regionStart, regionLength).map(Match::new);


public static class Match{
    // Properties
    public int levenshteinSimilarity;
    public boolean reverseComparison;
    public int regionStart;
    public int regionLength;

    // Constructor
    public Match(int levenshteinSimilarity, boolean reverseComparison, int regionStart, int regionLength){
        this.levenshteinSimilarity = levenshteinSimilarity;
        this.reverseComparison = reverseComparison;
        this.regionStart = regionStart;
        this.regionLength = regionLength;
    }
}
```

However this give me an error 'bad return type in method reference'. Can anyone shed some light on the issue?

Answer (score 2):

`Stream.of()` returns a `Stream` of the specified elements. Passing a method reference to `map` for that `Stream` would apply that method to each `Stream` element separately. Therefore, only a constructor that takes a single argument can work. However, `Match::new` references a constructor with 4 arguments.